# Androidplot: Decimal Places in Point Label

Tags: java, android, androidplot

I would like to be able to set the number of decimal places for point labels.  Currently, my point labels are overlapping one another like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aQ4q.png

Current label implementation is trivial:

```
myXYPlot.setPointLabelFormatter(new PointLabelFormatter(Color.BLACK));
```

Comment: could you be more specific

Comment: See http://androidplot.com/docs/using-axis-value-labels/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the PointLabeler interface to get the behavior you're after; you need to set the PointLabeler for each series that should use the custom formatting.  For example:

```
series1.setPointLabeler(new PointLabeler() {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.###");

    @Override
    public String getLabel(XYSeries series, int index) {
        return df.format(series.getY(index));
    }
});
```

It's a little less intuitive than applying formatting to domain and range labels but was necessary in order to allow each series to have its own point labeling scheme.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Nick is for old version.
The PointLabeler method has been moved into LineAndPointFormatter.
The latest working example has been provided by Nick in another thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39482297/9969285

Answer (score 0):

PointLabelFormatter() and the other *Formatter() APIs don't offer a way to choose your decimal format.  My guess is that you need to format your series data prior to calling plot.addSeries().

Comment: Yeah I guessed the same too.  I hope someone more knowledgeable in Androidplot can confirm this.