# Format point label on XYPlot

Tags: java, android, androidplot

Method described in [Androidplot tutorial](http://androidplot.com/point-labeling-tools-in-0-5-1/)
doesn't work with API version 1.1.0. There is no method *setPointLabeler()* in class *LineAndPointRenderer*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That documentation is for a very old version of Androidplot - that method has moved into LineAndPointFormatter:

```
LineAndPointFormatter formatter = new LineAndPointFormatter();
formatter.setPointLabeler(new PointLabeler() {
    @Override
    public String getLabel(XYSeries series, int index) {
        // your code here
    }
});
```