# Androidplot - Format PointLabel (remove decimals) on Bar Graph

Tags: androidplot

I have been searching for how to format the text (remove decimals) of point labels on Bar graph.
This is my code:

```
BarFormatter bf = new BarFormatter(Color.CYAN,Color.CYAN);
    PointLabelFormatter plf = new PointLabelFormatter();
    plf.getTextPaint().setColor(Color.BLUE);
    bf.setPointLabelFormatter(plf);
```

i can only set the color here. The label is displayed with decimals. How to remove it or set a decimal format in this?
This comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/39482297/9969285 here describes pointlabeler under lineandpointformatter. How to implement this for a bar graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be the same as what you linked - `BarFormatter` extends `LineAndPointFormatter`:

```
bf.setPointLabeler(new PointLabeler<XYSeries>() {
    final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");

    @Override
    public String getLabel(XYSeries series, int index) {
        return df.format(series.getY(index));
    }
});
```